# "Related question" why so?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, hyperlinks

Why do people make a point of linking questions to each-other? They write "related." Do they link that so the person asking may see his answer? 
Thank you

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/658.

Comment: @msh210 nice pun :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is that the other question may be of interest to people who are interested in this question. In some cases, the content in the other question may help answer this one. In others, it's just that they're on a similar theme. It's like a footnote in a book saying "See also Chapter 7."

Answer (score 4):

To add to [@Isaac's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/659/603), when a question is linked to another question, they show up in a separate section on the right hand column. The section is called "Linked" and is useful.